# OpenCart | 404 на страницах сайта после установки шаблона и демо данных

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте!
Установил LightShop на OpenCart 2.3.0.2 и пробовал на OCStore.
Главная работает а на остальных 404, как исправить?

Отключаешь ЧПУ и сайт вообще перестаёт работать.
Переустанавливал по несколько раз, ничего не меняется.

Ссылка на сайт: http://test2.truskahouses.in.ua/

Пробовал как на хостинге, так и на OpenServer'е.

Comment: P.S ранее на этом же хостинге уже был установлен магазин на этом же шаблоне и этой же версии OpenCart

Comment: это тот, который удалили по фтп впоследствии?